# Remove duplication code from methods that depend on return result of other method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, refactoring, code-duplication

In ASP.NET MVC application in controller class I have a method

```
        protected ActionResult VerifySanctions(string sanction)
        {

        bool hasSanctions = this.qualificationSanctionsService.HasSanctions(sanction);


        if (hasSanctions)
        {                               
              return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

        }
        return null;
        }
```

This method contains common logic from different other actions from different controller
I decided to create a base class for controller that will keep this method and derive other controller from it. But problem is in when I call this method from derived class actions I need to verify if not null and then return the result for example

```
    public ActionResult RegistrationTracking(EncryptedId sourceId)
    {
        // some code
        var registration = learnerRegistrationService.Get(sourceId);

        var result = this.VerifySanctions(registration.Qualification);
        if (result != null)
        {
            return result;
        }
         // some code
        return this.View();

    }
```

in other actions I need to verify if result not null again

```
    public ActionResult Index(EncryptedId achievableVersionId)
    {
        var achievableVersion = achievableVersionService.Get(achievableVersionId);

        var verificationResult = this.VerifySanctions(achievableVersion);
        if (verificationResult != null)
        {
            return verificationResult;
        }          

         //some code
        return View();
    }
```

And I want to avoid duplication code, can anyone help me with example or advise?
What I need that if don't pass verification by method VerifySanction() then do nothing, else return Action result.

UPDATE the actions could like this

```
        public ActionResult ModifyUnits(EncryptedId sourceId)
    {
        var registration = learnerRegistrationService.Get(sourceId);

        Check.Require(registration != null);
        Check.Require(registration.Enrolment != null, "QualificationEnrolment is null - RegistrationAmendments / ModifyUnits");
        var result = this.VerifySanctions(registration.Qualification, LookupOrganisationAchievableStatus.Sanction3);
        if (result != null)
        {
            return result;
        }

        if (!this.organisationAchievableService.IsAccessibleAchievableVersion(registration.Qualification.Id, this.GetOrganisationId()))
        {
            return new PopupFormResult().Notify(MUI.PleaseSelectACentre);
        }

        SetEnrolmentViewData(registration.Enrolment);

        ViewData["registrationId"] = sourceId;
        var isComposite = registration.Enrolment.IsComposite();
        ViewData["isComposite"] = isComposite;

        this.SetSelectedUnitsViewData(registration, isComposite);

        this.SetSelectedQualificationUnitsViewData(isComposite, registration);

        return this.PartialView("ModifyUnits", new List<UnitDisplay>());
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
 public ActionResult RegistrationTracking(EncryptedId sourceId)
    {
        var registration = learnerRegistrationService.Get(sourceId);                    
        return VerifySanctions(registration.Qualification, View());
    }

    private ActionResult VerifySanctions(Sanction sanction, ViewResult view)
    {
        bool hasSanctions = this.qualificationSanctionsService.HasSanctions(sanction);

        if (hasSanctions)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but in particular actions I have additional login not only return view what I need as I wrote above, if Verification doesn't pass shouldn't do something else return from action with action result

Comment: in examples in I've written very simple cases

Comment: Well, may be you can update question with sample, that does not fit my suggested sulution, or you can take a look at ancailliau answer, as it is more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a method in a default controller extended by all your controller
to embed this logic. For example,

```
private ActionResult ViewWithSanction(string sanction, ActionResult default)
{
  bool hasSanctions = this.qualificationSanctionsService.HasSanctions(sanction);
  if (hasSanctions) {                               
    return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
  }
  return default;
}
```

And then your method could looks like

```
public ActionResult RegistrationTracking(EncryptedId sourceId)
{
    var registration = learnerRegistrationService.Get(sourceId);
    return ViewWithSanction (registration.Qualification, View());
}

public ActionResult Index(EncryptedId achievableVersionId)
{
    var achievableVersion = achievableVersionService.Get(achievableVersionId);
    return ViewWithSanction (achievableVersion, View());
}
```

Comment: thank for answer this is good solution if there are no additional logic look at the updates in question I've added example

Comment: If addition logic is required, this http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/06/22/cleaning-up-posts-in-asp-net-mvc/ is probably worth reading. There might have something to inspire from.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `Func<ActionResult>` that will execute when `hasSanctions` is false

```
private ActionResult VerifySanctions(Sanction sanction, Func<ActionResult> whenNoSanctions)
{
    bool hasSanctions = this.qualificationSanctionsService.HasSanctions(sanction);

    if (hasSanctions)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    return whenNoSanctions();
}
```

And calling

```
 return VerifySanctions(registration.Qualification, ()=> { //any code that returns ActionResult });
```

**UPDATE:**

You could extract your not null part as separate method

```
private ActionResult WhenNoSanctions()
{
        if(!this.organisationAchievableService.IsAccessibleAchievableVersion(registration.Qualification.Id, this.GetOrganisationId()))
        {
            return new PopupFormResult().Notify(MUI.PleaseSelectACentre);
        }

        SetEnrolmentViewData(registration.Enrolment);

        ViewData["registrationId"] = sourceId;
        var isComposite = registration.Enrolment.IsComposite();
        ViewData["isComposite"] = isComposite;

        this.SetSelectedUnitsViewData(registration, isComposite);

        this.SetSelectedQualificationUnitsViewData(isComposite, registration);

        return this.PartialView("ModifyUnits", new List<UnitDisplay>());
}
```

And call VerifySanctions as

```
 return VerifySanctions(registration.Qualification, WhenNoSanctions);
```